# Separate Date and Time from datetime element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have lists inside a list containing 3 elements each, one of which is datetime. I need to modify the list to separate the date and time into their own elements and put them back in the list.

Sample input:

```
[[2, 13, '2019-02-02T07:00:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02T09:00:00']]
```

Desired output:

```
[[2, 13, '2019-02-02', '07:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02', '09:00']]
```

I'm able to isolate the time or the date using the code below, but cannot figure out how to get both:

```
from datetime import datetime

data_set_x = [[2, 13, '2019-02-02T07:00:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02T09:00:00']]

def convert_date(s):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for idx,item in enumerate(data_set_x):
    data_set_x[idx][-1] = convert_date(item[2])

for i in data_set_x:
    sql = "insert into data (ValueA, ValueB, Date) values (%s,  %s, %s)"

    print(sql, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

data_set_x = [[2, 13, '2019-02-02T07:00:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02T09:00:00']]

def convert_date(s):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), date_object.strftime('%H:%M')

for idx,item in enumerate(data_set_x):
    data_set_x[idx][-1], time = convert_date(item[2])
    data_set_x[idx].append(time)

for i in data_set_x:
    sql = "insert into data (ValueA, ValueB, Date, Time) values (%s,  %s, %s, %s)"

    print(sql, i)
```

Comment: This works best for my use-case, requiring minimal changes to what I already have.  I'm embarrassed it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `datetime` if the input and output are expected to be strings, it just adds unnecessary overhead.

```
def break_date_time(s):
    d, t = s.split('T')
    t2 = ':'.join(t.split(':')[0:2])
    return [d, t2]

data_set_y = [x[0:2] + break_date_time(x[2]) for x in data_set_x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import datetime

for item in data_set_x:
    # remove last element
    dt_str = item.pop()

    # convert 'str' to 'datetime'
    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    # append two 'str'
    item.append(dt_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    item.append(dt_obj.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

You may need to adjust the format of the new strings to fit your use case.

---

You could also just split the string by the `T` char in the original string (which will be faster than creating a `datetime` object), but the `datetime` object may be helpful if you want to specify a different format in either date or time than in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a slice assignment to edit the list:

```
from datetime import datetime

data_set_x = [[2, 13, '2019-02-02T07:00:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02T09:00:00']]

for item in data_set_x:
    item_dt = datetime.strptime(item[2], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    item[2:3] = [item_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), item_dt.strftime('%H:%M')]

print(data_set_x)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 13, '2019-02-02', '07:00'], [7, 8, '2019-02-02', '09:00']]
```